# Is there any iOS SDK equivalent of gethostbyname and inet_ntoa functions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, host, gethostbyname, nslookup

I saw several questions here, but is's still not clear for me. And could Apple reject for using standard gethostbyname function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the C standard library (at least according to POSIX). You can use all C library functions in your iOS app.